# How do I configure an HTTP connection to a GCP service to use a proxy?

Tags: python, http, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, proxy

My Python application needs to establish a connection to two Google Cloud Platform services: Google Groups and BigQuery. Connecting to the former requires the use of a proxy, but connecting to the latter with that proxy is not allowed.

So, instead of setting the proxy as an environment variable before the execution of the script - or during the execution of the script - I would like to specifically set the proxy for the connection to Google Groups.

Somehow, while the first approach works - proving that is not a proxy issue -, the second one does not, failing to find the oauth2 service to authorize the connection.

The example below is intended to list the groups from our organization. The connection is established following what's described in [this issue of the google-api-python-client project](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/1260).

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
import google_auth_httplib2
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from httplib2 import ProxyInfo, Http, socks
from urllib.parse import urlencodeenter code here

CLOUD_IDENTITY_SERVICE_NAME = 'cloudidentity'
CLOUD_IDENTITY_API_VERSION = 'v1'
SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-identity.groups'
]

proxy = ProxyInfo(
    proxy_type=socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP,
    proxy_host='http://proxy.local',
    proxy_port=99999
)
http = Http(proxy_info=proxy)
    
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename=_PATH_TO_CREDENTIALS,
    scopes=SCOPES
)

authorized_http = google_auth_httplib2.AuthorizedHttp(
    credentials,
    http
)

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    CLOUD_IDENTITY_SERVICE_NAME,
    CLOUD_IDENTITY_API_VERSION,
    http=authorized_http
)

query_params = urlencode({
    'page_size': 1000,
    'page_token': ''
})

request = service.groups().list(parent=f'customers/{_CUSTOMER_ID}')
request.uri += '&' + query_params
response = request.execute()
```

But the execution fails with the following error: `Unable to find the server at oauth2.googleapis.com`

The proxy is working as expected, as the script retrieves the groups data when setting up the proxy in the server before running the script: `export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.local:99999`.

Comment: Not sure that authorizedHTTP works with a proxy. But you can do the same manually if you want, it's boring but easy (based on your credential, generate a token. Then add the token in the `Authorization`  header as bearer token). And by the way, don't use a service account key file, it's a bad practice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `proxy_host` parameter of `ProxyInfo` needs to be specified without the protocol. Thus, changing `http://proxy.local` for `proxy.local` solves the issue.